# Should 'cause have a left or right curly quote?

Tags: punctuation, style

I tried to verify this with this Markdown converter:

https://dillinger.io/

However, it doesn't convert the single quote into a curly quote:

> 'cause

Should 'cause be written as ‘cause or ’cause?

(I'm not sure how to confirm this with Google.)

Comment: You could also abandon the convention of marking letter omissions and just use **cause**.  Why? Cause no one's gonna care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use quotation marks of either the single or double variety to indicate the omission of characters in written English. That is principally the job of the *[apostrophe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe)*, although that character is almost always rendered identically to the *right single quotation mark* for the typographically correct

> ## ’

For example,

> ## ’Cause of the holiday the mom ’n’ pop stores don’t open ’til Tuesday. At least, that’s what ‘Jake’ at Lowe’s said, and he’s lived here since the ’70s.

---

The problem you are encountering arises out of the historical practice of typewriters providing only a key for a straight single quotation mark (`'`), which is to be used to represent itself, apostrophes, left/opening single quotation marks (`‘`), and right/closing single quotation marks (`’`) and other look-alike characters.

From a data encoding standpoint, this is obsolete; there are now at least dozens of Unicode code points for very specific kinds of apostrophes, single quotation marks, accent marks, prime marks, and all the other kinds of short strokes used in punctuation in various writing systems. From a data *entry* standpoint, however, the problem remains. The vast majority of users are only interested in a character's appearance, not its technical definition, so the nuances of when to use `′` instead of `´` are lost, much less the difference between U+02BC `’` and U+2019 `’`. Even if they had a keyboard that could enter those characters, they wouldn't use them correctly and consistently.

Therefore, software may attempt to guess at the character you intend based on surrounding text. If `'` falls between an *n* and a *t*, it guesses that an apostrophe is needed; if `'` falls after a space, it guesses that you are opening a quotation, if it detects markup it might retain code point 27. In cases like yours, it will guess wrong. As with all so-called spelling and grammar checkers, it is not an authority, and as of 2018 at least, you should never rely on machines for making decisions about orthography, or anything else in your writing.

Comment: Thanks. So, technically, the answer is right curly single quote.